# How to merge two lists of strings (date and time) and treat them as DateObject

Tags: string-manipulation, date-and-time

I would like to merge two lists of strings (date and time) from my csv and then treat it as a DateObject:

```
time = Import[
    "C:\\Users\\Data Chanel.csv",
    "Table",
    "FieldSeparators" -> ";",
    NumberPoint -> ","][[3, 3 ;;]];
    date = Import[
         "C:\\Users\\Data Chanel.csv",
         "Table",
         "FieldSeparators" -> ";",
         NumberPoint -> ","
    ][[2, 3 ;;]];


combFunc =  Function[{date, time}, StringJoin[ToString /@ {date, time}], Listable][date, time]
```

And the result is: [image]

```
timeData = DateObject[combFunc, {"Day", ". ", "MonthName", ". ", "Year", " ", "Hour", ":","Minute", ":", "Second"}]
```

which changes year and time in first step as it can be seen in the picture

and DateObject doesn't work even when I apply it only on time or only on date or their combination.

Do you have any idea how to fix it?
Thank you for your advices!
Here is the link for the csv:

https://gofile.io/d/I6scno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you imported the data in `time` and `date`. Then we need to assemble these two in a form that suits the `DateObject`:

```
dat= MapThread[(#1 <> " " <> #2) &, {time, date}];
```

Then we  map `DateObject` with the necessary options onto every element of the list `dat`:

```
dates = DateObject[{#, {"Hour", "Minute", "Second" , "Day", 
      "MonthName", "YearShort"}} ] & /@ dat
```

dates is a list of `DateObject`;

[image: date[[1;;2]]]

Answer (score 2):

```
imported = Import["Data Chanel 1.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ";"];

dates = DateObject[#2 ~~ " " ~~ #3]& @@@ Transpose@ imported[[All, 2 ;;]]
```

[image]